# Pulling out sublists based on their `car`s

Tags: list, common-lisp, elisp, sublist

I am trying to build a web scraper with elisp, so I have parsed the target website (https://weather.naver.com)'s HTML into a huge list. For example, this list was a list fragment of the original HTML:

```lisp
(defvar *test* '(li
                 ((class . "item_time")
                  (data-tmpr . "2")
                  (data-wetr-cd . "7")
                  (data-wetr-txt . "흐림")
                  (data-is-daytime . "false")
                  (data-ymdt . "2020121100"))
                 "
                                    "
                 (span
                  ((class . "time day"))
                  "0시")
                 (i
                  ((class . "ico _cnLazy  night")
                   (data-ico . "ico_wt7"))
                  (span
                   ((class . "blind"))
                   "흐림"))
                 "
                                    "
                 (span
                  ((class . "blind"))
                  "2도")
                 "
                                "))
```

And want to pull out sublists by their `car`s. For example, I want to pull out all sublists starting with `data-tmpr` from `*test*` by giving `*test*` and `'data-tmpr` as inputs. So far, I have written this piece of code:

```lisp
(defun dotted-list-p (list)
  (and (listp list) (not (listp (cdr list)))))


(defun mapdot (func coll)
  `(,(funcall func (car coll)) . ,(funcall func (cdr coll))))


(defun mapfunc (tag coll)
  (if (listp coll)
      (if (equal (car coll) tag)
          coll
        (if (dotted-list-p coll)
            (if (equal (car coll) tag)
                coll
              '())
          '())
        (reduce #'append (mapcar (apply-partially #'mapfunc tag) coll) :initial-value '()))
    '()))


(defun find-by-tag (parsed-html tag)
  (if (equal (car parsed-html) tag)
      parsed-html
    (mapcar (apply-partially #'mapfunc tag) parsed-html)))
```

However, evaluating the following expression hits an error:

```lisp
ELISP> (find-by-tag *test* 'class)
*** Eval error ***  Wrong type argument: listp, "2"
```

I am baffled with the error message, since `"2"` must have come from the dotted pair `'(data-tmpr . "2")`, hence the recursive call `(find-by-tag '(data-tmpr . "2") 'class)` should yield `nil` because of this conditional expression:

```
(if (dotted-list-p coll)
    (if (equal (car coll) tag)
         coll
         '())
    '())
```

Why is evaluating `(find-by-tag *test* 'class)` resulting in an error?

Edit: typo.
Edit2: Better title.

Answer (score 4):

As with leetwinski's answer I'm not going to answer the direct question you asked, but rather to step back and try to solve the underlying problem.

I'm also going to to this in CL (`common-lisp` is in the tags!): I'm sure this can be done in elisp but, well.

First of all **you are not processing a bunch of conses here**: you're processing some tree structure, and that's the structure you should process.  That structure happens to be *represented* as a bunch of conses, but the *only* code that cares about that should be the code that makes the abstraction.

Here is an example of such code.  I have used the wrong names for things since this is really abstracting HTML (or XML), but I wrote it quickly.

- a tree is either a node or a blob;
- nodes have names, lists of attributes and lists of children, which are trees;
- blobs are not nodes and don't have any defined properties.
- attributes, which belong to nodes, have names and values.

Note that when I say 'nodes have lists of children' I mean that: it's fine to talk about lists when what you actually want *is* a list.  Here is the code which implements this abstraction:

```
;;; Things in the tree are either blobs or nodes
;;;

(defun treep (thing)
  (or (nodep thing) (blobp thing)))

(defun blobp (thing)
  (atom thing))

(defun nodep (thing)
  (and (consp thing)
       (listp (cdr thing))))

;;; Accessors for nodes
;;;              

(defun node-name (node)
  (assert (nodep node) (node)
    "~S isn't a node" node)
  (car node))

(defun node-attributes (node)
  (assert (nodep node) (node)
    "~S isn't a node" node)
  (cadr node))

(defun node-children (node)
  (assert (nodep node) (node)
    "~S isn't a node" node)
  (cddr node))

;;; predicate & accessors for attributes
;;;

(defun attributep (thing)
  (and (consp thing)
       (not (listp (cdr thing)))))

(defun attribute-name (attribute)
  (assert (attributep attribute) (attribute)
    "~S isnt an attribute" attribute)
  (car attribute))

(defun attribute-value (attribute)
  (assert (attributep attribute) (attribute)
    "~S isnt an attribute" attribute)
  (cdr attribute))

;;; Tree constructors (unused below)
;;;

(defun make-node (name &key
                       (attributes '())
                       (children '()))
  (assert (every #'attributep attributes) (attributes)
    "attributes ~S aren't" attributes)
  (assert (every #'treep children) (children)
    "children ~S aren't" children)
  (list* name attributes children))

(defun make-attribute (name value)
  (assert (not (listp value)) (value)
    "attribute values can't be lists because, sorry")
  (cons name value))
```

Note that there are a possibly excessive number of checks here.  But, well, if the thing that is producing these trees is botching them I want to know.

So now we have an abstraction for the trees we're making, we can now write code which walks over these trees looking for things, using only this abstraction.  A good approach do this is to write a *walker* which is a function which will walk over the tree for us, calling *visitor* functions on the various things it finds.  Here is a simple-minded implementation of one: note that the visitors get the stack of nodes above them which they can use to know where they are.

```
(defun walk-tree (tree &key
                       (node-visitor nil node-visitor-p)
                       (attribute-visitor nil attribute-visitor-p)
                       (blob-visitor nil blob-visitor-p))
  ;; A simple-minded recursive walker.  Visitors get two arguments:
  ;; the thing they are visiting and the stack (a list) of nodes above
  ;; it.
  (labels ((walk (thing stack)
             (cond 
              ((nodep thing)
               (let ((new-stack (cons thing stack)))
                 (when node-visitor-p
                   ;; node visitors want the current stack, not the
                   ;; new one
                   (funcall node-visitor thing stack))
                 (when attribute-visitor-p
                   ;; attribute visitors need the new stack so they
                   ;; can know which node they are attributes of
                   (dolist (a (node-attributes thing))
                     (funcall attribute-visitor a new-stack)))
                 (dolist (c (node-children thing))
                   ;; and the new stack is what we pass down
                   (walk c new-stack))))
              ((blobp thing)
               (when blob-visitor-p
                 ;; blob visitors just want the current stack
                 (funcall blob-visitor thing stack)))
              (t
               (error "mutant horror")))))
    (walk tree '()))
  tree)
```

And we can check this:

```
(defun print-tree-stacks (tree)
  (walk-tree tree
             :node-visitor
             (lambda (n s)
               (print (mapcar #'node-name
                              (cons n s)))))
  (values))
```

And now:

```
 > (print-tree-stacks *test*)

(li) 
(span li) 
(i li) 
(span i li) 
(span li)
```

OK, that smells OK.  Note that the walker is written purely in terms of the tree abstraction: if you changed the representation then nothing in the walker would change.  So now we can use this walker to pull out whatever information we're after.  Let's say we want to find attributes with specified names.

```
(defun extract-attributes-named (tree name)
  (let ((attrs '()))
    (walk-tree tree
               :attribute-visitor
               (lambda (a s)
                 (declare (ignore s))
                 (when (eql (attribute-name a) name)
                   (push a attrs))))
    (nreverse attrs)))
```

And we can test this:

```
>  (mapcar #'attribute-value (extract-attributes-named *test* 'class))
("item_time" "time day" "ico _cnLazy  night" "blind" "blind")
```

The trick is to define abstractions which describe what you want to do and then use those abstractions, without poking inside the actual representation.

Comment: This is really nice! Follow-up question here: what does `(declare (ignore s))` do? Even if I commented that expression out, `extract-attributes-named` seems to work equally well.

Comment: @Namudon'tdie: it tells the system that there's a variable binding (in this case one of the arguments of the function) that is unused.  That means that it should not warn about unused bindings, and it probably *will* warn if the binding *is* used.  There is an 'ignorable` declaration which is similar but says 'don't warn if it is unused, but it may be used'.

Answer (score 1):

*This actually doesn't answer the question about the error, but rather proposes a different solution.*

I have this idea, it may look a little bit hacky, but it still seems to do what you need. You can use `subst` for tree traversal, without actually substituting anything, but rather collecting needed elements:

```
(defun find-by-tag (data tag)
  (let ((res))
    (subst nil nil data :test (lambda (a b)
                                (declare (ignore a))
                                (when (and (listp b) (eql (car b) tag))
                                  (push b res))
                                nil))
    res))

CL-USER> (find-by-tag *test* 'data-tmpr)
;;=> ((DATA-TMPR . "2"))

CL-USER> (find-by-tag *test* 'span)
;;=> ((SPAN ((CLASS . "blind")) "2도") 
;;    (SPAN ((CLASS . "blind")) "흐림")
;;    (SPAN ((CLASS . "time day")) "0시"))

CL-USER> (find-by-tag *test* 'class)
;;=> ((CLASS . "blind") 
;;    (CLASS . "blind") 
;;    (CLASS . "ico _cnLazy  night")
;;    (CLASS . "time day") 
;;    (CLASS . "item_time"))
```

Comment: I'm surprised that binding nothing to a local variable: `(let ((res)) ... )` is possible. How is it possible and what does it do?

Comment: Oh, it's binding `res` to `nil`. I see.